# Exporting Matlab image for paper

Tags: image, matlab, printing

I am writing a paper for a scientific journal and I want to include images that I made with Matlab. The way I usually do this is by plotting the image in Matlab and interactively go to the plotting window in 'File->Save as..' and save the image as an eps. When I include the image in my paper (which I write with LaTeX) the image looks correct overall (there are no artifacts) but it does not look as sharp as on my screen. Is there a better way to save the images with better quality so that they do not look blurry when I insert them in LaTeX?
Thank you.

Comment: What does "not as sharp as on my screen" mean? Aren't you also viewing the paper on your screen? What exactly are you exporting, an image made up of pixels or something like a plot?

Comment: I don’t know what your problem is, you’ll have to do more to describe it. But try this tool for exporting: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig

Comment: Please provide a [mwe] (of both the Matlab plot creation/saving and Latex file) to show this, eps is a vector format so there should be no blur if your plot doesn't contain any images itself.